# Integrate Google Earth JS API with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, google-earth

I am rather new to angular, and trying to integrate it with google earth's javascript API.

I have done some work with on both, but never try to use them together. My motivation is to use the google earth module in an angular fashion, with controllers etc to manipulate the map.

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

I want the google module to be available as with the d3 module in the link above, through a factory that loads the script. Then be able use the google module when the script is loaded.

I have gotten this to work with the d3 module:

```
angular.module('d3', [])
.factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$window', '$q', '$rootScope',
    function($document, $window, $q, $rootScope) {
        var d = $q.defer(),
            d3service = {
                d3: function() { return d.promise; }
            };
        function onScriptLoad() {
            // Load client in the browser
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve($window.d3); });
        }
        var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.async = true;
        scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
        }
        scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

        var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        s.appendChild(scriptTag);

        return {
            d3: function(){ return d.promise; }
        };
    }]);
```

Which then is available through directives:

```
    .directive('d3Bars', ['$window', '$timeout', 'd3Service',
    function($window, $timeout, d3Service) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                label: '@',
                onClick: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
                    //code...
            }}
    }]);
```

I have tried to rewrite this to load the google loader JS module https://developers.google.com/loader/:

and then replacing "d3" with "google". and ofc the scripTag.src variable. Should this be correct?

```
function onScriptLoad() {
// Load client in the browser
      $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve($window.google); });
}
```

I then have a simple directive where I want to use the google JS object to load the earth api.
the "getApi"-module is similar to "d3service" in the d3 factory above.

```
    .directive('mapFrame' ['$window', '$timeout', 'getApi',
    function($window, $timeout, getApi) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {
                getApi.google().then(function(google) {
                    console.log(google);
                    google.load("earth", "1");
                    //more code..
                });
            }
        }
}])
```

in the html-file:

```
<div map-frame></div>
```

This way of doing it works with d3. I loads the script into the DOM, and can display some charts, which doesn't seem to happen with the google module. Looks like the directive never invokes the factory, since the javascript is never loaded into the DOM..

What is it that I'am missing, or isn't it even possible ?

Thanks!